# Stop integration in odeint with stiff ode

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I want to solve a stiff ode with odeint. I was following [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/stiff_systems.html) (rosenbrock4_dense_output stepper) but, my function can grow pretty quickly so I want to stop the integration if x(t)>xMAX.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586059/bound-an-odeint-variable/14588283#14588283), they have a solution for it but since I'm new with c++ I don't know how to implement this when using a rosenbrock4_dense_output stepper.

I would like to see how to write this specifically for rosenbrock4_dense_output stepper.

Comment: Just last week I added an example that finds the exact points where some threshold is crossed: https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/find_crossing.cpp, It uses the iterator interface of odeint together with a find_if to stop when the threshold is crossed. Then it does a bisection to approximate the crossing point, but you might not need that. To that adapt for rosenbrock you just have to change the stepper and the rhs function.

Comment: This seems to be doing exactly what I need, but I don't know how to make it work with the rosenbrock4_dense_output stepper.
Just changing 
runge_kutta_dopri5 to rosenbrock4_dense_output
and instead of state_type using vector_type:
where vector_Type is defined:
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector< double > vector_type;
is not all that is required.
Would you mind explaining how this would change for my specific case.

Comment: You also need to adjust the rhs, e.g. auto ode = make_pair( stiff_system() , stiff_system_jacobi() ); - see also headmyshoulder's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not easily possible with odeint. If you can use the range library [here](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) you can combine a `for_each` and a `find_if` algorithm.

Otherwise you need to write the loop yourself, which is also not that difficult and should be similar to this:

```
auto stepper = make_dense_output< rosenbrock4< double > >( 1.0e-12 , 1.0e-12 );
auto ode = make_pair( stiff_system() , stiff_system_jacobi() );

double t = 0.0;
double const end_time = 50.0;
double const dt = 0.01;
vector_type x( 2 , 1.0 );
const double y_min = 1.0;

stepper.initialize( x , t , dt );
cout << t << " " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << endl; // or some other output
t += dt;
while( t < end_time )
{
    if( t > stepper.current_time() )
    {
        // perform a real step
        stepper.do_step( ode );
    }
    else  
    {
        // perform a dense output step
        stepper.calc_state( t , x );
        cout << t << " " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << endl; // or some other output
        t += dt;
    }
    if( x[1] < y_min ) // or some other condition
    {
        cout << "Bound reached." << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the odeint iterators not work with rosenbrock_dense_out? Or are you referring to the problem that with find_if we can not access the trajectory?

Comment: The second problem: with `boost::range::find_if()` we can not access the trajectory and do the observation.

Comment: Would you mind writing explicitly how for the code will look with the rosenbrock4_dense_output stepper since I've been reading the documentation from odeint but I don't seem to get it right.

Comment: Ok, done. `stiff_system` , `stiff_system_jacobi`are taken from the stiff system example you are referring to.